# How much is ideal keepAliveTimeout for nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am facing an issue like server keeps returning 502 error. I debugged and found that query is executing and before it can complete connection is timed out. The query takes around 15-20 seconds to execute. I am using node-oracle on Ingress. I saw that default for keepAliveTimeout in nodejs server is 5 seconds. I increased to 10 seconds. But in this way, I will keep on increasing till I don't face any issue. It's not the right way of doing this. What happens if I keep keepAliveTimeout as 0? Any other approach to handling it?

Comment: keepAliveTimeout as 0 will make it wait for infinite time untill your nginx do not timeout the api itself.

Comment: @MohitSahu - Any impact on performance or memory?

Comment: if you are not  fetching large data from the DB than it will not leave any impact on the memory.

Comment: @hacker See this for more details and a test: https://github.com/pbininda/node8keepAliveTimeout You should be fine disabling this.

Comment: @MohitSahu How will the amount of data fetched from the database impact this setting?

Comment: @DanMcGhan - I did set it to 0. Still i see timeouts happening. Anyway i can prevent it from happening.

Comment: Could you show the exact error you're getting? Is it only an HTTP 502, or do you see something in the console?

Comment: client gets 502 error. and nothing in console. Server hits timeout function.

Comment: @DanMcGhan - One more thing is that, first time the request fails and client calls same api immediately and it goes through.. Not sure how to debug this.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in some code that you can share?

Comment: Not able to reproduce as it is occasional.

Comment: @DanMcGhan -  I figured it out that Ingress was closing the connection. I increased timeout and it worked fine.